# Processing Keypress BACKSPACE gets not detected

Tags: processing, backspace

I am creating a game with Processing and want to input a username. I know it is not perfect (first time processing), I can write every letter but the `backspace` does not work.
This is my Code:

```
void keyTyped() {
  if(status("getUsername")) {
    if(((key >= 'a' && key <= 'z') || (key >= 'A' && key <= 'Z') || (key >= '0' && key <= '9') || key == ' ') && (key != CODED && keyCode != ENTER)) {
      user.addLetter(key);
    } else if(key == CODED && keyCode == BACKSPACE) {
      user.remLetter();
    }
    System.out.println(user.getName());
  }
}
```

**User**

```
class User {
  String name = "";

  void addLetter(char letter) {
    this.name = this.name + letter;
  }

  void remLetter() {
    if(name.length() != 0) {
      System.out.println("rem");
      name = name.substring(0, name.length()-2);
    }
  }
}
```

**Input**

```
Jon[BACKSPACE]
```

**Ouptut**

```
J
Jo
Jon
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem? Or how I could improve my code?



I tried to use the demo code from `George Profenza` and it worked perfectly, but when I try to use this in my code, it does not work for an unknown reason...

Full code on: https://github.com/BeeTheKay/GameSnake.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have missed a little gotcha using [`key`](https://processing.org/reference/key.html):

> For non-ASCII keys, use the keyCode variable. The **keys included** in the ASCII specification (**BACKSPACE**, TAB, ENTER, RETURN, ESC, and DELETE) **do not require checking** to see if the key is **coded**, and you should **simply use the `key` variable instead of `keyCode`** If you're making cross-platform projects, note that the ENTER key is commonly used on PCs and Unix and the RETURN key is used instead on Macintosh.

Simply change:

```
} else if(key == CODED && keyCode == BACKSPACE) {
```

to

```
} else if(key == BACKSPACE) {
```

Additionally, you might want to delete a single character instead two:

```
name = name.substring(0, name.length()-2);
```

simply changing it to:

```
name = name.substring(0, name.length() - 1);
```

Here's a basic demo sketch mostly based on your code:

```
User user = new User();

void setup(){}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  text(user.name,5,15);
}

boolean status(String s){
  return true;
}

void keyTyped() {
  println(key == CODED, key, BACKSPACE, key == BACKSPACE);
  if(status("getUsername")) {
    if(((key >= 'a' && key <= 'z') || (key >= 'A' && key <= 'Z') || (key >= '0' && key <= '9') || key == ' ') && (key != CODED && keyCode != ENTER)) {
      user.addLetter(key);
    } else if(key == BACKSPACE) {
      user.remLetter();
    }
    System.out.println(user.getName());
  }
}

class User {
  String name = "";

  void addLetter(char letter) {
    this.name = this.name + letter;
  }

  void remLetter() {
    if(name.length() > 0) {
      System.out.println("rem");
      name = name.substring(0, name.length() - 1);
    }
  }
  
  String getName(){
    return name;
  }
}
```

(In the future, try to make it easier for other to support you by posting snippets of code that compile)

**Update** I've tried the github repo posted above and there seems to be a bug with [keyTyped()](https://processing.org/reference/keyTyped_.html) and the OpenGL based renderers (`P2D`, `P3D`):

- with `P2D`, `P3D` coded keys don't seem to trigger `keyTyped()`, however `keyPressed()`, `keyReleased()` do
- using the other renders: `JAVA2D` or `FX2D` work as expected.

This seems to be a [known Processing issue](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/4654), however it doesn't look like it will be fixed in the near future sadly.

Personally, this is the first time I hear of `keyTyped()` after all these years playing with Processing :) I'm used to `keyPressed()` / `keyReleased()`.

In the meantime you have at least two options:

1. If you really want to use `keyTyped()` use `size(600, 600, JAVA2D);` instead of `size(600, 600, P2D);` (and hopefully the performance/rendering will still be good enough)
2. Use `P2D`, but simply move the logic you currently have in `keyTyped()` inside `keyReleased()`

Comment: Your demo sketch works but when I even only press my backspace button nothing happens, it does not even register a key as typed

Comment: Strange that my sketch works. if you add `println(key,keyCode);` inside your `keyTyped()` function, does it print anything ? Also, I assume in your code your code you have a `draw()` function, right ? (otherwise there will be no key / mouse events)

Comment: I just used a `println("typed")` it does not print "typed" when i press `BACKSPACE`.
You could check out my code on Github (added the link in my question) if you want to help me

Comment: @BeeTheKay The code in the repo is mostly nicely organised and formatted: nicely done ! Lucky you: it appears you ran into a bug with `keyTyped()` and `P2D` :) 
See the updated answer above.